# MYSQL Summing of Column With Unique Results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I've got a many to many table p_to_t

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   p      |    t      |   weight  |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1      |   bob     |    40     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   2      |   sue     |    24     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   3      |   bob     |    90     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   4      |   joe     |    55     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   5      |   bob     |    33     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm looking to query for value t WHERE p IN(1,2,4,5) while summing the weight for each value of t.

This query: `"SELECT t, SUM(weight) AS sWeight FROM p_to_t WHERE p IN(1,2,4,5)";` just adds all the sums to the first "t" selected e.g;

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    t      |   weight  |
+-----------+-----------+
|   bob     |   152     |
+-----------+-----------+
```

When what I would like is:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    t      |   weight  |
+-----------+-----------+
|   bob     |   97      |
+-----------+-----------+
|   joe     |   55      |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `GROUP BY` clause on t

```
SELECT 
 t, 
 SUM(weight) AS sWeight 
FROM p_to_t 
WHERE p IN(1,2,4,5)
GROUP BY t
```

By the way, you will also get *Sue* with these values in the IN clause...

And not `97` for *Bob*, as `40 + 33` are more often `73`

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  And yes, I forgot about sue and added her points to bob.  Sorry, Sue.

Comment: @HowardZoopaloopa Sue will forgive.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t, SUM(weight) AS sWeight FROM p_to_t WHERE p IN(1,2,4,5) GROUP BY t
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da370/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add just Group by to your actual query. then you will get the below result.

```
SELECT t, SUM(weight) AS sWeight 
 FROM p_to_t 
WHERE p IN(1,2,4,5)
Group by t;

+-----------+-----------+
|    t      |   weight  |
+-----------+-----------+
|   bob     |   73      |
+-----------+-----------+
|   joe     |   55      |
+-----------+-----------+
|   sue     |   24      |
+-----------+-----------+
```